# how to disable child inside border in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

What I Have Tried Is?

```
Canvas Canvas=new Canvas();
Border Border =new Border();
Border.Child=Canvas;
Border.IsEnabled =true;
```

But IsEnabled Property Is not present in Border?What shall I Do Now??

Comment: You want Control.IsEnabled, maybe wrap in ContentControl?

Comment: i did not understand what you told !!
I need Contol for border....

Comment: Wrap your stuff in something that can be disabled.

Comment: `Border` is not an interactive control. It is mainly used for UI layout. It doesn't make sense to disable it. Please disable specific child controls (eg `Button`)

Answer (score 0):

i have used UserControl..

> USerControl user=new UserControl();
>     user.content=border;
>      user.IsEnabled=false;

UserControl has IsEnabled Property derived from Contol Class..